# How to add 2 digital waveform graphs, constructed from lists of points?

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode

Assume I have 2 lists of points `(x,y)` representing digital waveform graphs, which I can iterate through from left to right and which always start and end on `y = 0`.

For example:

```
Graph1 = [(0,0) (0,3) (4,3) (4,0) (9,0) (9,1) (11,1) (11,3) (15,3) (15,2) (17,2) (17,4) (19,4) (19,0)]
Graph2 = [(0,0) (0,1) (6,1) (6,0) (9,0) (9,1) (13,1) (13,0) (16,0) (16,1) (18,1) (18,0) (19,0)]
```

How would the pseudocode for the algorithm look like, or what's the name of the algorithm, that adds these 2 waveform graphs on the `y` value that returns the following list:

```
Result = [(0,0) (0,4) (4,4) (4,1) (6,1) (6,0) (9,0) (9,2) (11,2) (11,4) (13,4) (13,3) (15,3) (15,2) (16,2) (16,3) (17,3) (17,5) (18,5) (18,4) (19,4) (19,0)]
```

Comment: Could you go a bit more in-depth with how you reach the result?

Comment: The lists represents these kind of [graphs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndKTP.png). The points being where the values change. I want to add 2 of these graphs on the y-value (pile up) to create a similar graph. However this sometimes needs new points to be created, because the y-value can change at different x-values of the 2 graphs. I'm really sorry I can't draw them quickly right now.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? If so, please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a while, but maybe something like this?

```
list<Point*>* addProfiles(list<Point*>* pl1, list<Point*>* pl2) {
    if(pl1->empty()) return pl2;
    if(pl2->empty()) return pl1;
    list<Point*>* res = new list<Point*>;

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < pl1->size() && j < pl2->size()) {
        Point* p1 = pl1->at(i);
        Point* p2 = pl2->at(j);
        if(p1->x() < p2->x()) {
            res->append(new Point(p1->x(), p1->y()+p2->y()));
            i++;
        }
        else if(p1->x() > p2->x()) {
            res->append(new Point(p2->x(), p1->y()+p2->y()));
            j++;
        }
        else {
            res->append(new Point(p1->x(),p1->y()+p2->y()));
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i < pl1->size()) {
        res->append(new Point(pl1->at(i)->x(), pl1->at(i)->y()+pl2->last()->y()));
        i++;
    }
    while(j < pl2->size()) {
        res->append(new Point(pl2->at(j)->x(), pl1->last()->y()+pl2->at(j)->y()));
        j++;
    }
    return res;
}
```